# Report parameter validation message with Birt

Tags: validation, parameters, birt, maximo

I'm creating a BIRT report using certain parameters. I have an int parameter (Number of months) which values can be from 1 to 12.

I need to check if the value is bigger than 12. In such case it should show me a customized message and not an error like it is doing right now.

**Error:**

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: The validation for parameter "nummonths" fails.
```

**Current script:**

```
if (params["nummonths"].value > 12 )
    {
    false;
    } 
else
    {
    true;
    }
```

I create reports in BIRT to upload it to IBM Maximo Asset Management system. Maybe there is a different way to solve this in Maximo.

Thanks for your time! Hopefully will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dynamic text styled as a warning, and hide it (property "visibility") with  an expression such

```
params["nummonths"].value <= 12
```

There is an example of a such approach [here](http://www.visioneo.org/smartphone-economic), if we select more than 10 countries or more than 10 indicators, a warning label is displayed at the top of the report.

[image: Example of rptdesign]

An interesting point is, although a warning is displayed we can additionally create a rule to replace the wrong parameter value in a script such onCreate. This way the report can correctly run. For example in your case, we could do in a script:

```
if (params["nummonths"].value > 12){
  params["nummonths"].value=12;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also drop some report elements in "beforeFactory" when the parameter is wrong.