# Date parameter validation in Birt

Tags: java, validation, report, birt

I am trying to implement the validation to  Date parameter in Birt.
But script is not executing as expected.

Eg:

ParameterName : StartDate
Type : String

1. Validation for Length :

   Validation script in beforeFactory :

   errorcode=0; 
    var str=params["StartDate"].value; 
   if( str.length != 10 )
   {
   errorcode=1001;
   }

   HTML Text  in Report layout:

   // Error Codes

   var ERR_INVALID_DATE_FORMAT = 1001;
   var ERR_INVALID_START_DATE_VALUE = 1003;
   var ERR_INVALID_END_DATE_VALUE = 1004;

   // Error Messages​
   var MSG_INVALID_DATE_FORMAT ="Invalid Date Format";
   var MSG_INVALID_START_DATE_VALUE ="Invalid start date value";
   var MSG_INVALID_END_DATE_VALUE ="Invalid end date value";

   switch(errorcode;)
   {
   case ERR_INVALID_DATE_FORMAT:
   ​         alert( MSG_INVALID_DATE_FORMAT );
   break;

   case ERR_INVALID_START_DATE_VALUE:
   alert( MSG_INVALID_START_DATE_VALUE );
   break;

   case ERR_INVALID_END_DATE_VALUE:
   alert( MSG_INVALID_END_DATE_VALUE );
   break;

   default:
   alert(errorcode);
   }

The switch statement is not able to validate the  errorcode and it's not showing the alert message.

Note:
Earlier used custom format for date parameter but it's not able to detect the incorrect values for Date like aa/23/20145.

Is there any way to implement these validation?

Comment: This is a good question, see related [Adding date picker as parameter in BIRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555031/adding-date-picker-as-parameter-in-birt) for the common solution.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is, your HTML text code is a client-side script therefore it cannot directly access to variable "errorcode" you created in the beforeFactory event. For that you need to make use of "VALUE-OF" tag such below. Notice how this variable "errorcode" is declared in a HTML script:

```
<script>

// Error Codes
var ERR_INVALID_DATE_FORMAT = 1001, 
    ERR_INVALID_START_DATE_VALUE = 1003, 
    ERR_INVALID_END_DATE_VALUE = 1004,
    MSG_INVALID_DATE_FORMAT ="Invalid Date Format", 
    MSG_INVALID_START_DATE_VALUE ="Invalid start date value",
    MSG_INVALID_END_DATE_VALUE ="Invalid end date value",
    errorcode=<VALUE-OF>errorcode</VALUE-OF>;

console.log("Evaluating date format for code:"+errorcode);  

switch (errorcode) {
    case ERR_INVALID_DATE_FORMAT:
        alert(MSG_INVALID_DATE_FORMAT);
        break; 
    case ERR_INVALID_START_DATE_VALUE:
        alert(MSG_INVALID_START_DATE_VALUE);
        break; 
    case ERR_INVALID_END_DATE_VALUE:
        alert(MSG_INVALID_END_DATE_VALUE);
        break;         
    default: 
        alert("Format seems valid, error code returned is:"+errorcode);
}

</script>
```

However it is probably a better practice to apply this kind of validation step in a server-side script, in particular it would be easier to maintain. You have an example of a such approach in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771359/report-parameter-validation-message-with-birt). Using a javascript calendar as suggested by the topic pointed by James would also improve users experience. I hope it will help.